# botium project in eclipse with multiple botium.json not working

Tags: automation, chatbot

I have setup botium project according to direction given in https://chatbotsmagazine.com/5-steps-automated-testing-of-chatbots-in-eclipse-ef4c3dcaf233 and its working fine for single botium.json file.

but when i try to setup multiple connector together ex-
1)botium_dialog.json

```
{
  "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      "PROJECTNAME": "jokes",
      "CONTAINERMODE": "dialogflow",
      "DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID": "###",
      "DIALOGFLOW_CLIENT_EMAIL": "###",
      "DIALOGFLOW_PRIVATE_KEY": "###",
      "DIALOGFLOW_USE_INTENT": false
    }
  }
}
```

2) botium_watson.json

```
{
  "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      "PROJECTNAME": "IBM Watson Conversation Sample",
       "SCRIPTING_UTTEXPANSION_MODE": "all",

      "SCRIPTING_FORMAT": "xlsx",
      "SCRIPTING_XLSX_STARTROW": 2,
      "SCRIPTING_XLSX_STARTCOL": 1,
      "CONTAINERMODE": "watson",
      "WATSON_USER": "#",
      "WATSON_PASSWORD": "#",
      "WATSON_WORKSPACE_ID": "#"
    }
  }
}
```

in the same project but running 1 at a time using

> mocha --reporter mochawesome --reporter-options
>   \"reportDir=reportsDialog,reportFilename=index.html,code=false\"
>   --convos ./spec/convo/dialog --config botium_dialog.json --exit spec "

its giving error

> Error: Capability 'CONTAINERMODE' missing
>         at BotDriver._getContainer (node_modules\botium-core\src\BotDriver.js:316:13)
>         at async.series (node_modules\botium-core\src\BotDriver.js:154:30)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "--convos" and the "--config" command line parameters are actually for the [Botium CLI](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-cli), not for mocha. You either switch your test scripts to Botium CLI, or you configure Botium in a way to use several configuration files and several convo directories. My recommendation would be to pack each section in an own subdirectory - so you have a "botium_dialog" and a "botium_watson" directory, each with it's own package.json, botium.json, spec/convo folders etc.

With some configuration changes, it is also possible to use your current folder structure.

1. Add multiple botium.spec.js in spec folder:

*botium_dialog.spec.js*:

```
const BotiumBindings = require('botium-bindings')
const bb = new BotiumBindings({ convodirs: [ './spec/convo/dialog' ] })
BotiumBindings.helper.mocha().setupMochaTestSuite({ bb })
```

*botium_watson.spec.js*:

```
const BotiumBindings = require('botium-bindings')
const bb = new BotiumBindings({ convodirs: [ './spec/convo/watson' ] })
BotiumBindings.helper.mocha().setupMochaTestSuite({ bb })
```

2. Add multiple test scripts to your package.json:

package.json:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "test_dialog": "BOTIUM_CONFIG=botium_dialog.json mocha --reporter spec --exit spec/botium_dialog.spec.js",
  "test_watson": "BOTIUM_CONFIG=botium_watson.json mocha --reporter spec --exit spec/botium_watson.spec.js"
}
...
```

3. Run both of the test scripts

For example:

```
npm run test_dialog
npm run test_watson
```